# Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't work very well after wallpaper change

Tags: unity, desktop-background

I made [a wallpaper](http://lucaszanella.deviantart.com/art/The-Hitchhiker-s-Guide-to-the-Galaxy-Wallpaper-376329514) and added it to my desktop, but when I minimize a window, it just stops working.

After I rebooted and logged in, this happened:

[image: mishmash of images]

And now if I minimize something again, the system will crash.

Oh... I hid the desktop icons to visualize better and now that I was trying to put them back, Unity Tweak Tool doesn't work either.

What can I do?

Comment: How did you add it to the desktop?

Comment: What you mean? The login stuff? When I edited my desktop background it happened! Is an error that was annoying me, now I`m reinstalling - and unfortunately will lost all my archives because I don`t have a backup!

Comment: There is no indication in your text as to your method.  With more information, it is easier for others to spot clues to diagnose the issue and help you.  If you did nothing unusual, simply used the standard GUI to set a background, then this is likely a bug. If you were following a tutorial, editing files manually, etc., there easily could be something else happening. You don't need to lose any data here -- there are various ways to get to it if you don't reinstall over it....